# Add string to Browserify pipeline instead of file

Tags: javascript, browserify

It's possible to add a file to a Browserify bundle:

```
browserify(path)
    .add('./say_hello.js')
```

How can a string be added like this?

```
var jsString = "console.log('hello');";

browserify(path)
    .anotherAddFunction(jsString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Make a variable to hold all the files you want to be contained in the bundle, send them to a stream, bundle them up together, and then create a stream to merge them into.

```
gulp.task('bundler', function() {

//put your input files into the files variable so it can get bundled together

var files = ['./app/mainA.js','./app/mainB.js','./app/mainC.js'];

//Use the map to map the files to a stream function
    var tasks = file.map(function(entry)) {
        return browserify([ entries: [entry]])
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source(entry))
            .pipe(rename({
                extname: 'bundle.js'
        });
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
    });
    return es.merge.apply(null, tasks);
})
```

As far as adding a file to a preexisting bundle, you can recreate the bundle by modifying the code above, recreating the bundle after adding a file to the variable, just create a function to add the file to the files variable, and call the gulp bundler task to initialize/update the bundle, the bundle will be named the same, so it should still work, just with the new added file to the bundle. I have not tested this in a live webapp, if you would like I can try implementing something of the sort and get back to you.

**EDIT:** 
Alternatively you can use [externalize](https://github.com/epeli/browserify-externalize) to do asynchronous loading of files into a preexisting browserify bundle.

Comment: The problem is that I'd like to generate JavaScript code dynamically (e.g. as a string), and pass it to browserify to append the code to the file stream. As far as I see your solution only concatenates already existing files. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes you are right, but since browserify will live reload the new content, re-bundling the files before passing it on to the stream should simulate the same.

Comment: Have you ever worked with externalize? It does asynchronous loading into preexisting bundles, that is a good alternative, don't know why I did not think of it sooner.

Comment: Xavid, could you please provide a short example how to add dynamically (in the code, as a string, and not as an external file) created content to the browerify pipe? E.g. as in my question the logging code snippet.

Comment: Ok before writing something, give me a bit more detail on how you will be adding this new string? Are you going to have some sort of entry for a user to enter new code, which will then pass it to the back end to put into the browserify bundle? Are you going to save any new code into a file, and then push that into the bundle? I read your initial question, which was adding file to preexisting bundle, and I assumed you would save the new code into a file, which was already listed in the bundle files list, or could be added to be re-bundled. So just briefly, where will these strings be entered?